# Hive query from twitter data in HDFS

Tags: mysql, hadoop, twitter

I have been following this article on how to analyze twitter data with Hive: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/11/analyzing-twitter-data-with-hadoop-part-3-querying-semi-structured-data-with-hive/

I have set up flume to collect twitter data and write into HDFS. I have set up a hive table that refers to the same HDFS location.

When I run a command like this from hive: 
        SELECT entities.user_mentions[0].screen_name FROM tweets;

I get the following response:
OK
Time taken: 0.16 seconds.

It does not matter what query I run, I don't get any results.

As I am new to Hive, am I expecting to see the results in the Hive command line, or do I have to mine the result from mySQL. mySQL is the metastore DB.

Comment: is the data available in hdfs path? can you share the create table command

Comment: Yes, I can see the twitter file in HDFS as per the path established in Flume.

Comment: Here is the create table query: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (
  id BIGINT, 
  created_at STRING,
  source STRING,
  favorited BOOLEAN,
  retweeted_status STRUCT<
    text:STRING,
    twitteruser:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>,
    retweet_count:INT>,
  entities STRUCT<
    urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
    user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
    hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
  text STRING,
  twitteruser STRUCT<
    screen_name:STRING,

Comment: name:STRING,
    friends_count:INT,
    followers_count:INT,
    statuses_count:INT,
    verified:BOOLEAN,
    utc_offset:INT,
    time_zone:STRING>,
  in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
) 
PARTITIONED BY (datehour INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
LOCATION '/hduser/flume/twitter';

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) from tweets; Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 1
2016-11-13 19:22:39,192 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-11-13 19:22:46,980 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 100%, Cumulative CPU 1.43 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 1 seconds 430 msec
Ended Job = job_1479056865151_0001
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 1.43 sec   HDFS Read: 5797 HDFS Write: 101 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 1 seconds 430 msec
OK
0
Time taken: 21.587 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)

Comment: Which hadoop version you use ?

Comment: Hadoop version is 2.7.2 on Ubuntu. Hive version is 2.1

Answer (score 0):

When hive data is partitioned with directory, then it needs to be rapaired to see partition/partitions. Thus, running `msck repair table your_table_name`  should solve your problem.